# Google Earth ignoring gx:altitudeOffset in KML files

Tags: kml, 3d, google-earth, polyline-creation, linestring

I am currently writing software that creates 3D polylines and outputs these in KML format. According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestring) it is possible to define an altitude offset via gx:altitudeOffset to raise or lower the line. This is quite handy to avoid 3D polylines rendered in Google Earth to "disappear" below the ground in areas where Google's topographic data isn't as accurate as one would wish. However, it seems that gx:altitudeOffset has no effect in Google Earth - at least for me.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Answer (score 3):

You need to state whether you are clamping you lines to the ground or lines have elevation values that are raising the line into the sky (relativeToGround) or are absolute (measured from seal level.)

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/altitudemode#clamptoground

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/altitudemode#relativetoground

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/altitudemode#absolute

Possibly Related:

**BUG ALERT** in Google Earth Version 7

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650836/altitude-clamp-to-ground-error-in-ge-7-0-1-8244